# I have a table and I want to extract the row in reverse order of columns in shell script

Tags: shell, awk, scripting, columns

The table looks like this:

```
1|Hunk|First|London
2|Hero|Second|London
3|Will|First|Pow
4|Thomas|Second|Pow
5|Venus|First|Berlin
```

I want to print the output as:

```
Berlin|First|venus|5
```

i want to print only the final line.

Comment: Do you want to get the last row with columns in reverse order? Or something else? Does your table always contain exactly 4 columns? Please explain this in your question.

Comment: Last row with columns in reverse order is what i want.and yes always 4 columns

Comment: Your sample output shows the 5th line, not the 4th line. (Or do you count starting with 0?) Do you want exactly the 4th or the 5th line even if your file has more lines or do you want the last line? To get the last line you can combine any of the working scripts with `tail -1`.

Comment: i want the final line.kindly help .my table has 5 lines

Comment: As I already wrote: combine any of the scripts proposed in the answers in a pipe with `tail -1`

Answer (score 3):

Using perl:

```
perl -alne 'print reverse split /(\|)/'
```

(sorry for the obfuscation)

or...

```
perl -alne 'print reverse /[|]|[^|]+/g'
```

Comment: Nice idea to capture the pipe to include it into the fields to split. I came up with `perl -F'\|' -lape '$_= join "|", reverse @F'` which is a lot less elegant.

Comment: @glennjackman, thank you! `join "|", reverse` is also very cool!

Answer (score 1):

Or you can pipe output of your table to sed

```
$ cat filename | sed -r 's/(.*)\|(.*)\|(.*)\|(.*)/\4\|\3\|\2\|\1/g'
```

Comment: You are right, edited

Comment: You don't need `cat filename |`, just use `sed ... filename`

Comment: Sure, that an other option, but it can also parse things from stdin

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
 awk -F '|' '{for (i=NF;i>0;i--){if (i!=1) printf $i"|"; else printf $i};printf "\n"}' file.csv

London|First|Hunk|1
London|Second|Hero|2
Pow|First|Will|3
Pow|Second|Thomas|4
Berlin|First|Venus|5
```

To print only the last line

```
awk 'END{print}' file.csv | awk -F '|' '{for (i=NF;i>0;i--){if (i!=1) printf $i"|"; else printf $i};printf "\n"}'
```

Comment: it prints the whole table.i want only the final line to be print.kindly help

Comment: @hunkmaster check my update

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, no awk.

```
$ paste -d\| <(cut -d\| -f4 file) <(cut -d\| -f3 file) <(cut -d\| -f2 file) <(cut -d\| -f1 file)
London|First|Hunk|1
London|Second|Hero|2
Pow|First|Will|3
Pow|Second|Thomas|4
Berlin|First|Venus|5
```

```
$ sed -E 's/(.*)\|(.*\|)(.*\|)(.*)/\4|\3\2\1/' file
London|First|Hunk|1
London|Second|Hero|2
Pow|First|Will|3
Pow|Second|Thomas|4
Berlin|First|Venus|5
```

Comment: Exactly what I wrote

Comment: Almost, but not completely  :)

Comment: That first pipeline would actually parse the file _four_ times!

Comment: Thank god the input file is just a few bytes... :)

Answer (score 0):

Done with below command

```
 k=`awk '{print NR}' u.txt | sed -n '$p' `
z=`awk -F "|" '{print NF}' u.txt | sort |uniq`
praveen@praveen:~$ for ((i=1;i<=k;i++)); do for ((j=$z;j>=1;j--)); do awk -v i="$i" -v j="$j" -F "|" 'NR==i{print $j}' u.txt ; done| perl -pne "s/\n/ /g"| awk '{print $0"\n"}'|sed -r "s/\s+/|/g"| sed "s/|$//g"; done| sed '/^$/d'
```

output

```
k=`awk '{print NR}' u.txt | sed -n '$p' `
z=`awk -F "|" '{print NF}' u.txt | sort |uniq`
for ((i=1;i<=k;i++)); do for ((j=$z;j>=1;j--)); do awk -v i="$i" -v j="$j" -F "|" 'NR==i{print $j}' u.txt ; done| perl -pne "s/\n/ /g"| awk '{print $0"\n"}'|sed -r "s/\s+/|/g"| sed "s/|$//g"; done| sed '/^$/d'

London|First|Hunk|1
London|Second|Hero|2
Pow|First|Will|3
Pow|Second|Thomas|4
Berlin|First|Venus|5
```

Answer (score -1):

```
cat filename | sed -r 's/(.*)\|(.*)\|(.*)\|(.*)/\4\|\3\|\2\|\1/g' > output.file
```

now if you check your output file, you can see your desire output.